# How to build SplendidCRM 2.1 under VS2012?

Tags: asp.net, c, dynamics-crm

I am getting this error when i am tryiing to build the Spledidcrm 2.1

> Could not load type 'SplendidCRM._controls.PartsDesigner'. C:\Program
>   Files\SplendidCRM Software\Web Site_controls\PartsDesigner.ascx 1
>
> Unknown server tag 'SplendidCRM:ExportHeader'. C:\Program
>   Files\SplendidCRM Software\Web Site\Accounts\ListView.ascx 29

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get 2.1 working in VS 2012, please download our 8.5 Community Edition.  Our 8.5 version already supports VS 2012.  Our 8.5 release has a ton of features that should make it a better choice.

Version 2.1 was developed for VS 2005.  Please review our 
[SplendidCRM Platform Support Matrix](http://www.splendidcrm.com/Products/PlatformSupportMatrix.aspx) for more information.

Support Staff
SplendidCRM Software, Inc.